# Is there a mention of Nava-Durga in Vedic scriptures?

Tags: vedas, devi, durga, taittirya-upanishad, nava-durga

The [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C4%81ty%C4%81yan%C4%AB) page on Ma Katyayini mentions:

> **She is first mentioned in the Taittiriya Aranyaka part of the Yajurveda.** Skanda Purana mentions her being created out of the spontaneous anger of Gods, which eventually led to slaying the demon, Mahishasura, mounted on the lion given to her by Goddess Parvati. This occasion is celebrated during the annual Durga Puja festival in most parts of India

Is there a mention of Goddess Katyayini or any other Nava Durga forms in the Tattiriya Aranyaka or any Vedic scripture? If not which is the oldest scripture to refer to any of them (separately or together as a group)?

Comment: Shakti is Mother Maya and gives lot of worldly fruits easily, do you think ancient wise sages who were trying to get out of Maya and making others to get out of it would worship her or encourage her's worship. Its for Kalyuga when people are unwise and short lived that the secret worship of Shakti and Tantra are revealed to mankind

Comment: No there is no mention.

Comment: Good question @Dr. Vineet Aggarwal

Answer (score 3):

Navadurgas are mentioned in Skanda Purana. They were mentioned during Daksha Yajna.

> Expressly commanded by Rudra himself the extremely powerful Vīrabhadra came to the sacrificial enclosure accompanied by the nine Durgās and others.**The nine Durgās were Kālī, Kātyāyanī, Īśānā, Cāmuṇḍā, Muṇḍamardinī, Bhadrakālī, Bhadrā, Tvaritā and Vaiṣṇavī.** A big multitude of Bhūtas also entered the sacrificial enclosure of great refulgence. Śākinīs, Ḍākinīs, Bhūtas, Pramathas, Guhyakas, a host of Yoginīs (in circular formation) along with the sixty-four (Tantras) —all these entered the sacrificial enclosure suddenly. *- Skanda Purana I.1.3.49-51*

The same list is also found in the Siva Purana (Siva Purana, Rudra Samhita, Sati Khanda, Chapter 33, verses 11-12).

> 11-12. Mahākālī went ahead for the destruction of Dakṣa accompanied by nine Durgās Viz:—Kālī, Kātyāyanī, Īśānī, Cāmuṇḍā, Muṇḍamardinī, Bhadrakālī, Bhadrā, Tvaritā and Vaiṣṇavī and the goblins.

Reference -

[Skanda Purana translated by G V Tagare](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc365950.html)

[Siva Purana translated by J L Shastri](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-english/d/doc226053.html)

Comment: Thanks for this reference unfortunately this list is different from the nine forms we know of..

Answer (score 2):

Devi atharvasirsha upanishad mentions the names of Kaalaratri and skandamata forms of navadurga.

Comment: Please add the scriptural reference from the Upanishad that would help your answer

Answer (score 0):

The term "Nava-Durga" and the concept of her nine forms (Navadurga) are not found in the Vedic scriptures. This idea gained popularity during the medieval period and is described in later Hindu Puranas and Tantric texts.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).